# Android - How to search and get a element from a JSON by not downloading the its whole array?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am currently developing an simple app that user must login his/her account. In order to log in an account, I must search for a specific element from JSON which contains the username and password, but I must avoid downloading the whole JSON array. Is this possible? and if not, what is the correct implementation should I do. DON'T WORRY ABOUT THE SECURITY OF THIS EXAMPLE BECAUSE ITS JUST AN EXAMPLE AND I JUST WAN'T TO SEE YOUR ANSWERS PERTAINING TO THE QUESTION. THANK YOU!

For example, this is what my JSON array looks like:

```
"UserAccount":[
    {"username":"John", "password":"123"}, 
    {"username":"Anna", "password":"456"}, 
    {"username":"Peter", "password":"789"}
]
```

Comment: These seems dangerously insecure. Security aside, your server code will have to provide some way to filter the data on the server side before it gets sent back to your app.

Comment: @ScottW  does it mean that I am required to get all of the data from the json first, then put it into a android json array and search for the specific element from here?

Comment: Basically, yes. If you don't want the data going over the wire, then your server has to be smart enough to only send you the data that you need.

Comment: I think they teach dangerous code somewhere and people ask questions about their homework assignments here.  IRL people are doing this?

Comment: I just shown an example of what I want to do so the example would be easier to understand. But no need to worry, I will implement that on further development of my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use stream parser, such as

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

It works in a way similar to SAX XML parser. Just ask yourself a question: is it worth it? If the JSON is small, you'll not get any gain. If it's big - you probably have a design problem.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to put Username and Password as parameters in your API, and return `OK` when Username and password match or `FALSE` otherwise.
After that you may download the JSON string specific to the user.

Comment: ... and PLEASE don't send unencrypted passwords to your API unless you want your application to be hacked and your users spammed the first day. Read about MD5 password hashing as a first measure.

Comment: yes, i just shown an example of what I want to do so the example would be easier to understand. But no need to worry, I will implement that on further development of my application. BTW, thanks!